# What decides the mapping of an operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Let's consider a groupoid $(G,\circ )$. Therefore the operation is defined as $\circ: G\times G\rightarrow G$. An example of this groupoid maybe $(\mathbb{N},+)$. But what decides that $(1,2)$ maps to $3$ via the operation of addition i.e., $1+2=3$ and not $4$ or any other natural number?

Similarly, what decides that the unary operation of differentiation on a function $f(x)$ maps to $\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow b}\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$?

Comment: *We* decide that. It's what us humans think is useful, so we define it that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is the job of **definitions**. In theory, you investigate arbitrary groupoid structures, for which you do not question where the operation (or even the underlyikng set) came from. In concrete examples, you specify the operation by a *definition* -- and of course need to show that this operation this definition gives you does indeed produce a groupoid.

---

Recall that for $\Bbb N$, we have the Peano axioms, which deal with the special element $0$ of $\Bbb N$ and the successor function $S$, and introduce the concept of inductoin as well as the concept of a recursive definition.

The operation $+\colon \Bbb N\times \Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is defined in terms of $0$ and $S$ as follows:
$$ n+0:=n $$
for all $n$, and then recursively by
$$ n+Sm=S(n+m).$$
If we give the usual interpretations to the symbols $1,2,3$, namely $1:=S0$, $2:=S1$, $3:=S2$, then we find that indeed
$$ 1+2=S0+SS0=S(S0+S0)=SS(S0+0)=SSS0=3.$$
(Why do we define $+$ as above and not differently? Because the operation defined this way turns out to be very useful in applications! E.g., by experience, this seems to be very helpful in predicting the outcome of having one apple and putting two apples next to it)